# switch case ignoring conditions in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am using a switch to test the value of a variable.
The variable, `$sizeTotal`, could contain either a string or a number. In the below example, I am expecting the switch to trigger the default case.
However, it goes to the first case every time and I don't know why...

```php
$sizeTotal = "test";
$extraCharges['2'] = 1000;

switch ($sizeTotal) {
    case ($sizeTotal < $extraCharges['2']):
        $var = 40;
        return $var;

    case ($sizeTotal >= $extraCharges['2']):  
        $var = 60;
        return $var;

    default:
        $var = 1000;
        return $var;
}
```

Comment: You're using the switch statement wrong, it's meant for checking a single value of a variable, not a condition. You probably want to use an else-if construction which IS able to check conditions. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: The string is converted to 0 and 0 is less than 1000. that is why your first condition is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the **[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**

> **If you compare a number with a string** or the comparison involves numerical strings, then **each string is converted to a number** and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

You're placing a string in a comparison.